# Room Dao whit Hilt Broke after adding a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-room, dagger-hilt

I am working in an Android App using Kotlin. The project has an MVVM Arquitechture wiht Room Repository, i am using also Dagger Hilt for Dependecy Injection. My project was compiling perfectly but when i added a new fragment, i started getting this error:

> -failed
> -:app:kaptDebugKotlin
> -ItemDao.java
> -Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
> -Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
> -Not sure how to handle delete method's return type. Currently the supported return types
> are void, int or Int.
> -Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
> -Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
> -Not sure how to handle update method's return type. Currently the supported return types
> are void, int or Int.
> -[Hilt]
> -java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

When i go to the link of the error, Android Studio say me:

> ItemDao.Java Files under the "build" folder are generated and should
> not be edited

Does anyone know why this could be happening? I really don´t know wht to google anymore to find the solution

I already try to clean cache and restart and clean project and rebuild it.

My project:

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {


    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(item: Item)

    @Update //(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun update(item: Item)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete (item: Item)

    @Query ("SELECT * from item WHERE ID = :id")
    fun getItem(id: Long): Flow<Item>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item " +
            "WHERE product = :product ORDER BY feature1 ASC")
    fun getProducts(product: String): Flow<List<Item>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY editDate")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<Item>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE product = :product AND (brand LIKE :searchQuery OR insideNumber LIKE :searchQuery OR feature1 LIKE :searchQuery OR feature2 LIKE :searchQuery OR feature3 LIKE :searchQuery)")
    fun getSearchQuery(product: String, searchQuery: String): Flow<List<Item>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE (brand LIKE :searchQuery OR insideNumber LIKE :searchQuery OR feature1 LIKE :searchQuery OR feature2 LIKE :searchQuery OR feature3 LIKE :searchQuery OR product LIKE :searchQuery)")
    fun getSearchQueryAll(searchQuery: String): Flow<List<Item>>
}


@Entity(tableName = "item")
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = newProductId(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "insertDate") val insertDate: String? = getCurrentDate(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product") val product: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "owner1") val owner1: Int? = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "owner2") val owner2: Int? = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "insideNumber") val insideNumber: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "location") val location: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "brand") val brand: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "feature1") val feature1: Double? = 0.0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "feature2") val feature2: Double? = 0.0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "feature3") val feature3: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "price") val price: Double? = 0.0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "currency") val currency: String? = "$",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type") val type: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "status") val status: String? = "no informado",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "observations") val observations: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "editDate") var editDate: String? = getCurrentDate(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "editUser") val editUser: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "excelText") val excelText: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "photos") var photos: String? = "0"
)

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCustomListUtil(): CustomListUtil{
        return CustomListUtil()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideItemRepository(
            itemDao: ItemDao,
            itemsApi: ItemsApi,
            customListUtil: CustomListUtil
        ) : ItemRepository {
        return ItemRepository(itemDao, itemsApi, customListUtil)
    }

 }

    @Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RoomModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideItemDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): ItemRoomDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            ItemRoomDatabase::class.java,
            ItemRoomDatabase.DATABASE_NAME
        )
            .createFromAsset(ItemRoomDatabase.DATABASE_ASSET)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideItemDao(itemRoomDatabase: ItemRoomDatabase) : ItemDao{
        return itemRoomDatabase.itemDao()
    }


}


@HiltAndroidApp
class MachineStockApplication : Application()


@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        installSplashScreen()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Retrieve NavController from the NavHostFragment
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)

    }
}
```

And Gradle File

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
    id "dagger.hilt.android.plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ferpa.machinestock"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    kapt {
        correctErrorTypes = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0-alpha02"

    // Firebase
    implementation platform ('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common-ktx'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:8.0.1'

    //ExifInterface
    implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.3"

    // Room
    def room_version = "2.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-common:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // Lifecycle
    def lifecycle_version = "2.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"


    // Navigation
    def navigation_version = "2.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"

    // Adaptive Design
    implementation "androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.2.0"


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // Retrofit
    def retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3"

    // Retrofit with Moshi Converter
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.11.0"

    // Picasso - Loading and cache Image
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    // Coil
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil:2.0.0-rc01"

    //Hilt
    def hilt_version = "2.38.1"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"

    //SplashScreen
    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-rc01"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i solved it by updating gradle dagger hilt plugin and dependencies, from 2.38.1 to 2.42. In any case, i don´t understand why did the problem arise in first place

Comment: Hey, can you please mention the version of dagger hilt plugin that helped solve the problem, it will help others with similar issue.